# Javax.mail in JNLP

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start, jakarta-mail

I have a problem with my program. I develop in Netbeans, and when i run the program it is working fine. i built it, created a *.jar file, and updatet it in my JNLP file.

here comes the trouble. as i'm using javax.mail.* in my program, the jnlp package just ignores all parts of it.

Just to be clear, i'm working on a mail client. now i can check the numbers of the mails in the inbox. that is what the program ignores in JNLP.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Incorporate a javamail implementation. The Apache Geronimo implementation is convenient from an licensing standpoint. That is, get a JAR file containing an implementation of javax.mail (other than the one built into j2ee) and package that into your JNLP package.

Comment: and how do i do that? sorry i'm a newbie in JAVA yet, it is for my school exam.

Comment: Well, you download it, you add it to your classpath ... and then you need to do something I know nothing about: include it in the JNLP package.

Answer (score 1):

I think all you need to do is to sign java mail implementation (either native or some 3rd party) `JAR`'s, add them to your `JNLP` file:

```
<resources>
   <jar href="mail-jar1"/>
   <jar href="mail-jar2"/>
   <!-- more -->
</resources>
```

...and then drop them along with your main `JAR` to your web server of choice.

Answer (score 0):

In order for your program to have access to the network and communicate with a mail server,  you need to sign all of the jars and include in the jnlp file this code:

```
<security>
    <all-permissions/>
</security>
```

If you use the Java EE mail implementation, then you need to include two jar files in your library:

```
<resources>
    <jar href="lib/activation.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/mail.jar"/>
</resources>
```

I like to place all of the library jar files in a separate folder, which is what netbeans normally does for you when it builds you app (look in the dist folder).

You also asked "can u offer me a way to run this program on my computer without netbeans and command prompt?"

That is pretty much the whole point of jnlp.  You can launch the program from a web browser.  The java tutorial contains many examples of this: 
For example: [JButton example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)

If this is the way you wish to deploy your application, you can read [the Web Start developers guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/contents.html).